# How to access placeholder text color of XLFormRowDescriptor

Tags: ios, objective-c, xlform

So, I know how to set the placeholder text of a XLFormRowDescriptor item:

```
[rowZIPCodeInput.cellConfig setObject:@"wheee" forKey:@"textField.placeholder"];
```

I can edit the color of the text using

```
[rowZIPCodeInput.cellConfig setObject:[UIColor pp_yellow] forKey:@"textLabel.textColor"];
```

But I can't figure out how to edit the color of the placeholder text. Is something like

```
[rowZIPCodeInput.cellConfig setObject:[UIColor pp_yellow] forKey:@"textField.placeholder.textColor"];
```

possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
XLFormRowDescriptor * row = ......
NSAttributedString *string = ....
[row.cellConfig setObject:string forKey:@"textField.attributedPlaceholder"];
```

https://github.com/xmartlabs/XLForm/issues/241

use an attributed string